# Apache spark: permission denied for files uploaded to job's staging directory

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I wrote an apache spark job that uses some configuration file. When I run this job locally, it works fine. But when I submit this job to a YARN cluster, it fails with a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Permission denied)`

I submit my job with the following command:

```
bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 1 --files /home/user/app.conf --class org.myorg.PropTest assembly.jar
```

It uploads assembly.jar and app.conf file to a subdirectory of the .sparkStaging directory in my home directory on HDFS.

I'm trying to access `app.conf` file on the following line:

```
ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("app.conf"))
```

When I upload a file with a name other than `app.conf`, it fails with a FileNotFoundException as expected.

But when I upload `app.conf`, it also fails with a FileNotFoundException, but with message that permission to ./app.conf is denied. So, it seems that it can gain access to this file, but can't gain required permissions.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. An uploaded file is added to driver's classpath, so it can be accessed as resource:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.parseResources("app.conf")
```